# Multiplication and Division unsigned integers

Tags: c, time, overflow, unsigned, multiplication

In my program , I have to perform arithmetic operations on unsigned integers.

- The variable a has a range from 0 to 4294967295.
- The variable b has a range from 0 to 32.

When I check the boundary condition by taking the maximun values for a and b,I am getting 0 as the answer since overflow occurs when I try to multiply **a** and **MAX_NS**.Ideally I should get 7 as the answer.How could I write the program such that overflow is taken care of and I get 7 as the answer and hopefully it works for other valid value range for a and b.Thanks.

```
#include "stdio.h"

#define MAX_NS 1000000000

 int main()
 {
    unsigned int a =  4294967295;
    unsigned int b =  32 ;

    unsigned int c = ((b * MAX_NS)/a);
    printf("%d",c);


 }
```

**Edit:**Please note that I can't use unsigned long long.I can use only unsigned int for the variables.

Comment: By using `unsigned long long`? You are dividing by the max unsigned value so all results (except one) that are within range of `unsigned int` will be `0`.

Comment: There is no way to use order of operations alone to obtain the same result you would get if the computations were performed with arbitrary-size intermediates.  Possibly there are tricks you could play that are specific to the input values (simplest: `c = 7;`), but other than those, the best you can do is to explicitly promote to a wider type, such as `uintmax_t`.

Comment: I don't see why you expect the answer to be 7.  The full precision answer will have the five low-order bits all zero, and the 32 bits above that all one.  How do you get 7 out of that?

Comment: "... perform arithmetic operations on unsigned integers. ... `a` has a range from 0 to 4294967295".  Hmm, certainly for division it is "`1 to 4294967295".

Comment: `#define MAX_NS 1000000000` --> `#define MAX_NS 1000000000ull`

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution as  Weather Vane suggested

```
#include "stdio.h"

#define MAX_NS 1000000000

int main()
{
    unsigned long long a = 4294967295;
    unsigned long long b = 32;

    unsigned long long c = ((b * MAX_NS) / a);
    printf("%llu", c);
}
```

Comment: but even when I use a smaller 'a' value(suppose 50000000) , I am not getting the correct answer.Should be 640 but i am getting 38.What could be the reason?

Comment: Something else must be problem. I have checked this code and it prints 7.

Comment: @GopalaKrishna in your example `b * MAX_NS` is `32000000000` which is too large to store in 32-bit `unsigned int`, no matter *what* you then divide by.

Comment: Do you want to show you print screen? As I told you, something else is problem, not code.

Comment: I changed the main program: unsigned int a =  50000000;
  unsigned int b =  32 ;
  
  unsigned int c = ((b * MAX_NS)/a);
  printf("%d",c);.I am getting 38 as the answer

Comment: Initial problem was that integer value is greater than max allowed for unsigned int types. If you divide initial number by 2, then problem is not initial anymore. You can use unsigned int if you decrease numbers. Otherwise, you must use long long

Answer (score 0):

The key is that the product `b * MAX_NS` must be computed using wide enough math.

Make certain at least one of the `*` operands is `unsigned long long`.

With large enough `b` and small enough `a`, the quotient will need a wider type to avoid overflow;

```
#include "stdio.h"
// #define MAX_NS 1000000000
#define MAX_NS 1000000000LLU

int main(void) {
  unsigned int a =  4294967295;  // type may remain unsigned 
  unsigned int b =  32 ;         // type may remain unsigned 

  unsigned long long c = ((b * MAX_NS)/a);
  printf("%llu",c);
}
```

Alternatively, coax the multiplication gently by multiplying by `1ull`.  In general avoid casting as in `(unsigned long long) b * MAX_NS`.  Rampant practice of casting surprisingly sometimes *narrows* the math which could happen here at a later date with `uintmax_t b`.

```
#define MAX_NS 1000000000

int main(void) {
  unsigned int a =  4294967295;  // type may remain unsigned 
  unsigned int b =  32 ;         // type may remain unsigned 

  unsigned long long c = ((1ull * b * MAX_NS)/a);
  printf("%llu",c);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but our hardware supports only 32 bit,can't use unsigned long long..

Comment: @GopalaKrishna Even an 8-bit processor can support `unsigned long long`.  A compliant C compiler will form the necessary instructions to realize 64-bit types and math.  Unusual requirements like "only use up to 32-bit math" should be in the _original_ post.